# Misunderstanding with ladder operators: $(a^\dagger)^k a^k\overset{!}{=}N^k$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

When assuming that the ground state is not degenerate one can show using
$$
N=a^\dagger a \quad [a,a^\dagger]=1
$$ 
 that there is exactly one eigenstate with norm 1 for every eigenvalue in $\textrm{Spec}(N)=\mathbb{N_0}$ given by 
$$|k\rangle=\frac{(a^\dagger)^k}{\sqrt{k!}}|0\rangle$$
But I'm confused because by applying k-times the annihilation operator on this $|k\rangle$ I can construct the normed state 
$$
\frac{a^k}{\sqrt{k!}}|k\rangle\overset{!}{=}|0\rangle$$
with eigenvalue 0. Because the ground state is non-degenerate this state has to be equal to $|0\rangle$. Combining both equations
$$|k\rangle=\frac{(a^\dagger)^k}{\sqrt{k!}}\frac{a^k}{\sqrt{k!}}|k\rangle=\frac{N^k}{k!}|k\rangle=\frac{k^k}{k!}|k\rangle.$$
Clearly something is wrong here. Can someone point me to my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is by assuming $(a^{\dagger})^k a^k = N^k$, which is not true. Once you have $(a^{\dagger})^k a^k = (a^{\dagger})^{k-1} N a^{k-1}$ you need to "pull" $N$ to the right or to the left, and each movement through a ladder operator results in a numerical factor due to the commutation relations.

Comment: Thank you. One can find $[N,a^j]=-ja^j$ by induction and show that everything works out fine.

Answer (score 0):

The notation of the exponentiation is not to be taken by the letter. The $a^k$, as well as $a^{\dagger k}$, means that you have to apply $k$-times the operator. So

$$
\frac{(a^\dagger)^k}{\sqrt{k!}}\frac{a^k}{\sqrt{k!}}|k\rangle = \overbrace{\frac{a^\dagger a^\dagger\cdots a^\dagger}{\sqrt{k!}}}^{\text{k-times}}\overbrace{\frac{a a\cdots a}{\sqrt{k!}}}^{\text{k-times}}|k\rangle = \frac{a^\dagger a^\dagger\cdots a^\dagger Na a\cdots a}{k!}|k\rangle
$$

and so on.